# read csv in rb mode and and convert to a list of list of strings in python3

Tags: python-3.x, file, csv, io, byte

I have a csvfile that gets passed in a binary mode only (rb).  Fhe file object already gets read in this mode and that's how it gets passed.  I want to convert that to a a list of lists.

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i

file=open('data.csv','rb')
```

I want to convert this to strings

```
[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

how do I get to do this in python3.  I think i get errors like

```
_csv.Error: Iterator should return strings, not bytes( did you open the file in text mode?)
```

How can I change the file read in bytes to strings or perhaps write into csv ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to convert a list of lists to string, right?
If so, you could do it like this:
`a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
`and then 
`a = (repr(a)).replace("'", "")`

Comment: i dont read it as a csv file though.  I get the file after it gets read in the file mode 'rb'.  So they are in bytes and not strings.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you should read it as a binary file? What's the content of the CSV in terms of data? If you can answer, of course

Comment: Reading a file thats uploaded by flask app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to read the file in python 3 as below:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(f.stream)
```

Ref to link:

[https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5t7h3p/opening_an_uploaded_file_in_flask/][1]